# Assembly language confusion

Tags: assembly

I am really struggling with understanding this assembly language question and after looking at the mark scheme I just cannot figure out why my answer differs from the one given.

The question is as follows

> **Figure 5** shows an assembly language program together with the contents of a section of the main memory of the computer that the
>   program will be executed on.  Each main memory location and register
>   can store a 16-bit value.
>
> The assembly language instruction set that has been used to write the
>   program is listed in **Table 1** on the next page.
>
> **Figure 5**
>
> ```
> LDR R1, 100
> LSL R2, R1, #2
> ADD R1, R1, R2
> LDR R3, 101
> CMP R3, R1
> BEQ labela
> MOV R4, #0
> B labelb
> labela:
>  MOV R4, #1
> labelb:
>  STR R4, 102
>  HALT 
>
> |---------------------|----------------------|
> |    Memory Address   | Main Memory Contents |
> |     (in decimal)    |      (in decimal)    |
> |---------------------|----------------------|
> |        100          |         10           |
> |---------------------|----------------------|
> |        101          |         50           |
> |---------------------|----------------------|
> |        102          |         80           |
> |---------------------|----------------------|
> ```
>
> **Question:** Complete the trace table below, in decimal, to show how the values stored in the registers and main memory change as the
>   program in Figure 5 is executed.  You may not need to use all of the
>   rows.

Trace Table:

[image: Trace Table]

Table 1:

[image: Table 1 Picture]

The answer I have come up with is this:

[image: answer]

But the answer on the markscheme is this (a 1 has been added in the 102 column):

[image: markscheme answer]

What I thought might be happening here is the program is exiting out of the labela branch and then resuming the code at the point after it branched to labela. However, if this was the case then the value of memory location 102 would be 0.

**Could someone please explain to me why a one is transferred into memory location 102 after executing branch labela?**

Thank you in advance to anyone who replies! Sorry if this is quite a long question, I am just really stuck, and after much attempt of trying to figure this out on my own I am not sure where else to go.

Comment: Is this LC-3?  It looks like ARM except for the addressing-mode syntax.

Comment: I believe it is an assembly language instruction set made by my examining board. Table 1 shows the syntax for the language

Comment: Why do you have valus as decimals? You have shift instructions here which causes shifts painfull. I would start from binary representation.

Comment: That calls is "AQA assembly".  It looks exactly like ARM, but with simplified addressing modes.  (`MVN` is a big clue that it's based on ARM.)  Strangely they seem to have removed indirect branches or any call/ret equivalent, so there'd be no way to write code that returned to right after the BEQ even if you wanted to.  (Real ARM has `bl`, branch-and-link, which saves a return address in a register.)

Comment: Does it matter actually? It can be as well as made up asm

Comment: @Antoniossss: It doesn't matter, I just wanted to tag this question properly so others could find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone please explain to me why a one is transferred into
>   memory location 102 after executing branch labela?

Its because labels are only for your convinience. Compilator translates them into program memory offset and later on every occurence of label is replaced with that program instruction offset (address).

Label is not like method or function in higher level programming language. Knowing that, follwoing lines are executed one by one from labela to `HALT`

```
labela:
 MOV R4, #1   // move #1 into R4
labelb:   // there is no such thing in program instuctions, just go on!
 STR R4, 102  // save #1 into mem102
 HALT        //halt
```

so once you get to `labela`, there is no turning back ;)